# Session cannot remain for a long time its automatically destroyed

Tags: php, session

I have an issue with session , my session is automatically destroyed after few minutes of inactivity ,i think its must be 24 minutes i.e. 1440 seconds.I want to session remain for a long time , i am using .user.ini file on the server and set **session.gc_maxlifetime** to 31557600 seconds and **session.cookie_lifetime** to 31557600 but nothing happened for me .Its still logout after 1440 seconds of inactivity .I have also attached session value of png image of phpinfo.
I hope your answer or any help will work for me.Thanks.[image]

Comment: Have you set `session.gc_maxlifetime` and `session.cookie_lifetime` _before_ start the session with `session_start`?

Comment: @nope i wrote only session_start();

Comment: if you do `echo ini_get('session.cookie_lifetime');` before `session_start`, whay do you get?

Comment: wait a min i m checking

Comment: its right said i.e. 31557600

Comment: can you check if your cookies are set with the right lifetime? do you call `session_unset` / `session_destroy` somewhere in your application? have you saw the answer of @Pedro Lobito about the `session_save_path`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92077/discussion-between-amy-and-federico).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not  sure why your settings aren't working but I use the following on my scripts to overwrite the `php.ini` settings for `session maxlifetime` and `session_save_path`:

```
session_save_path('/pathto/writable/dir/on/your/account');
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 24*60*60); // 24 hours; change as necessary
session_start();
```

---

**NOTE:**
The `session_save_path` is important because the default `path` is `/tmp` and it may get deleted by the system administrator on a daily/week? basis.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, it's always been related to the `php.ini` file. In your case, the master and local values for `session.gc_maxlifetime` contradict. (gc stands for garbage collect) They don't have to agree with each other, since the local value is used for the running script. It just means there's two php.ini files on your system, located in different places, and the local php.ini file is overriding the master php.ini file settings. But, I'd be *VERY* suspicious of any files on your server which call [`session_start()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) which use the master php.ini file, or call `ini_set(...)` within the script itself. The way this works is that no matter what the value is set to, it only has meaning when it's time to do garbage collecting. And garbage collecting is done by `session_start()` but you can also trigger garbage collecting in other ways such as [`SessionHandler::gc`](http://php.net/manual/en/sessionhandler.gc.php) or a cronjob as explained later in this post. When called, it checks the last modified time of the file on the server storing your session information. If the number of seconds that elapsed since then is greater than the current `session.gc_maxlifetime` value, it will destroy the session. Note this is the last modified time, not the last accessed time, so you'll want to change your session data frequently to prevent it from getting deleted if it's not changing. You should also be aware that there is a setting here, called `session.lazy_write` which, if enabled, and is enabled by default, *WILL NOT* update the last modified time of the session file in the event which the session data did not change. Thus you'll want to disable this if you want to minimize the chances of sessions being destroyed early for some unknown reason, or store a timestamp on the session so the data is always changing and you know when the session was last used, if old, you can manually call [`session_destroy()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php). To start another session, you can commit with [`session_write_close()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php) then recall `session_start()`. Or, do all 3 at once with [`session_regenerate_id(true)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php).

Nextly, if you initialize a session with `session_start()` with your intended settings, and continue to call `session_start()` with the intended settings with each request, awesome. But, once any file on your server calls `session_start()` with a different value for `session.gc_maxlifetime`, either from using the master php.ini value in your case, or the script calling [`ini_set(...)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) and ignoring the master value, it will check the file's last modified time against a different value and destroy your session despite your intended settings - is assuming it gets elected to be one of the 1 in 100 requests which have to garbage collect.

Another thing to be concerned with is `session.cookie_lifetime`. A value of 0 here turns the cookie into a browser session cookie. This means if the user closes their browser, then the session cookie will be deleted by the browser. Your master value is using 0. But your local value is using 31557600 (the average seconds in a year). So you should be fine here. But keep your eyes open if any scripts on your server override this value, use a value of `0`, or use the master php.ini file.

You should also be aware of the default 1% garbage collecting *CHANCE* that a session will be destroyed as defined by `session.gc_probability` and `session.gc_divisor` which default to 1 and 100 respectively. Garbage collecting is done when `start_session()` is called, if, and only if, the request "randomly" gets picked to be the request to manage the Garbage Collecting. This means that even if the number of defined seconds for a session elapsed for it to expire, `start_session()` *STILL* won't garbage collect even for this expired session. Rather, most users will notice their sessions expire exactly to schedule due to the cookie the browser keeps track of having its timestamp expire. But the session isn't enforced until PHP garbage collects as per the garbage collection change when `start_session()` is called. If you want sessions to be wiped clean when they've expired, and start a new one, you should use [`session_regenerate_id(true)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php). The `true` here means trash the `$_SESSION` data tied to the previous session and toss them a different session id as though their session expired.

You should also be aware that some systems, such as debian-based systems, have a cronjob which runs every 30 minutes to garbage collect based on the master php.ini configuration information.
See the comment here by Christopher Kramer: http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php
I cannot verify if the above information about debian systems is true, but I've considered [garbage collecting](http://php.net/manual/en/sessionhandler.gc.php) with a cronjob before to speed up users' requests so no one user gets stuck having to wait for their request to go through due to the maintenance which a cronjob could be handling.

**In terms of solutions here:**
One solution here is to adjust the master php.ini value, if you have access to it, then search your server for any PHP files which might be calling `ini_set` to see if there's any files conflicting with your settings to make sure they're not causing the unexpected behavior.

Another solution would be to limit such conflicts the script might be encountering by: *(1.)* renaming the `session.name` to something other than `PHPSESSID`. And/or *(2.)* changing the `session.save_path` path. Either of these by itself would suffice and avoid script conflicts.

A temporary fix might be to do something like change your `session.gc_probability` to `0` so the session garbage collecting NEVER happens. Or make it a much smaller chance by using something like session.gc_probability=1 and session.gc_divisor=100000. Then setup a cronjob to call [`SessionHandler::gc`](http://php.net/manual/en/sessionhandler.gc.php)

See http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php for more session config information.

Lastly I'd like to point you to this post which suggests good practices to prevent session hijacking, and for the most-part is the post I referenced when putting this post together: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1270960/466314
Note that it uses an approach to sessions which makes sure sessions expire on time, and not later (although browsers do a good job of this already with cookie garbage collecting). And it also makes changes to sessions, keeping track of the session last used time, so the session data is always changing to avoid the issue with `session.lazy_write`.

This concludes my suggestions. If you can narrow down the issue, try searching stackoverflow or asking a new question.

Comment: **TL;DR** something like `ini_set('session.save_path',realpath(dirname(dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'])) . '/session'));` (calling dirname on a directory tells you the directory of the directory) would be an ok solution to avoid script conflicts. Just keep in mind all the concerns mentioned in the post and make sure to store a timestamp in the session like the post here suggests: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520237/how-do-i-expire-a-php-session-after-30-minutes/1270960#1270960

Answer (score 1):

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1270960/3514119) :

> The best solution is to implement a session timeout of your own. Use a
>   simple time stamp that denotes the time of the last activity (i.e.
>   request) and update it with every request:
>
> ```
> if (isset($_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY']) && (time() - $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] > 1800)) {
>     // last request was more than 30 minutes ago
>     session_unset();     // unset $_SESSION variable for the run-time 
>     session_destroy();   // destroy session data in storage
> }
> $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] = time(); // update last activity time stamp
> ```
>
> Updating the session data with every request also changes the session
>   file's modification date so that the session is not removed by the
>   garbage collector prematurely.

Comment: OP's not asking how implement session timeout.

Comment: But if she does he/she can set the desired timeout.

Comment: If OP's problem is that his session run out after 1440 seconds, then your suggestion can not help

Comment: what should i do in this condition , because @Tsukeyomi answer didn't help me